# How to detect Zip Code against Int type

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, papaparse

I am struggling with a brain teaser. Maybe I'm just tired today, but I can't figure how to solve this one, and could use some help.

Flow:

```
papa.parse( convert csv -> to JSON) -> Map columns to DB columns -> Upload to DB
```

In step 3, map columns, the user is provided a drop down to select which db column to map to. I need to match the types from json to db column, but there is an edge case that is causing this to be a brain teaser for me that I can't quite figure out.

Zip Codes. In this example, zip codes should only be allowed to upload to string columns, so as to not lose '00123' format, leading-zero zip codes in an integer column (which translates '00123' as 123) but there are also cases of '#####' format integers, so I can't just use a regex with a certain format.

Any ideas?

Comment: what does `'#####' format integers` mean? Sounds like you need to check `typeof` or always use `toString()`

Comment: What i mean is a zip code is '#####' right? 


What if the user means for it to be an integer? an integer who's format is '#####'? either 50000 or 00005? I can't know what format of ints the user is uploading, because it's a csv converter. I'm trying to figure out how to validate the correct type, if zip code, must be a string, if not a zip code, then int? I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: If zip codes should only be allowed to upload to string columns, why do you care about how they look as integers? Zip codes are NOT integers. Zip codes will code in two formats: xxxxx and xxxxx-xxxx. Whatever you do, you need to handle both.

Comment: I don't care how zip codes ook as integers, but say they upload a 5 digit integer? Say they have an integer that is 5 digits that is NOT A ZIP CODE? How can I tell the difference?


Or say they have a leading zero zip code? How do I PREVENT THAT FROM BEING AN INTEGER and force it to be a STRING?


How do I tell the difference?

Comment: there are lists of valid zip codes out there if you need to actually validate that the 5 digits make up a true zip code

Comment: Again, even if I do that, and it matches a real zip code, how can I tell that the user intended for it to be a zip code and not an integer?

Comment: sounds like you have issues with your data source if you don't know what field to be expecting

Comment: Are you saying you don't know the column structure? If column structure is defined where is the problem...user would enter zip in zipcode column

Comment: The difference between what? A valid and an invalid zip code? If that's the problem, then you need to validate against a list of valid zip codes. There are third party libraries to do this. Or you could contact USPS.

Comment: Something is seriously missing from the problem description here ... or there is no real problem

Comment: @charlietfl agreed with both comments 100%

Comment: Column structure is defined. 

I have a 5 digit value. I need to programatically determine if it is a int or a zip code, if it matches an existing zip code. That is the problem. How do you do that without doing a type conversion to see if it converts? Because we don't want to convert the data type... Honestly, this conversation has been educational in that I need more info from the client... there's pieces missing for me apparently, so thanks for the discussion

Comment: @Joseph Duty, not an issue with the data source, but rather, the entire purpose of the app is the user can map csv data to db data, and we need to have dynamic types. However, the way we were doing things converted a zip to an int every time, making 5 digit zips look like 3 digit ints, instead of staying a string, confusing the client.

I don't know why I can't ever have straight forward problems with straight forward questions...

Comment: From your comments, you need your destination db to have zip stored as string, then it wont convert it to 3 digits, but will persist whatever is passed in (should be 5 digits, or possibly 9).  Why don't you want to do a .ToString() conversion?  If the data can't convert to a string, then you know its not valid, and you should figure out how to handle that use case

Comment: Unfortunately, the straightforward answer is that there is no way to determine if a 5 digit number is meant to be a zip code or an integer, unless you have more information about it.  Does the csv have the column name as the first row?  If so, you can get more information from that.

Comment: It already is a string. (to prevent losing leading zero's in zip codes)

This is what I mean. It IS a string, All data coming in is a string by default, but say it isn't a zip, instead it's a 5 digit int, and they want to map it to an integer column? Well too bad, it's a string, data types don't match, try a different column... This is the issue I'm trying to work around!!!

Comment: to me `zipcode` refers to US zipcodes which are numerical so you already want them as string for the padding....just doesn't seem to be a problem here. Logic about user wanting to enter integer and not zip doesn't make any sense in a structured column

Comment: Read more carefully charlietalskdf, plase before dismissing what I'm trying to carefully articulate.

The issue is there are MORE THAN JUST ZIP CODES IN A 5 DIGIT FORMAT. The user has the ability to map a csv, in an interface, to whatever column they so choose. I need to match those types so I don't attempt uploading the wrong types to the wrong columns, yeah? So say they have a 5 digit field in a row, and they map this to an int column, well it's a string because 5 digit ints could be zip codes, and I don't want to lose those leading zeroes, but it's not an int, its a zip, so no validation.

Comment: I can't make it any easier to understand. The user can upload whatever format they want from another data source, and I need to PROGRAMMITCALLY DETERMINE WHETHER 5 DIGITS IS A ZIP OR AN INT!

Comment: I'm NOT asking how to make a 5 digits into a string, i'm NOT asking how to make a zip code an integer... I'm asking HOW CAN I TELL THE DIFFERENCE PROGRAMMATICALLY BETWEEN A ZIP AND AN INT!?

Comment: if it IS a zip, it cannot be converted to an int, but then say it matches a real life zip code, 00123, for example, but the user intends for it to be an int... I can't figure out how to distinguish that.

Comment: Map your column indexes first. You will know then if it is zip or other data

Comment: I give up. I can't articulate this any better. I'm going to go punch myself until I come up with an answer.

Comment: sounds like you are trying to allow people to map fields incorrectly.  you also are saying that this column they are mapping it to is both an int and a string at the same time.  ("All data coming in is a string by default, but say its a 5 digit int... and they want to map it to an integer column") why do they want some zips to be ints and some to be strings?  If you don't know what data to expect (by using column headings), then how can you possibly know what to map it to or even how to validate it?

Comment: Certainly not what I'm saying, I'm saying there are multiple columns, and I'm simply trying to type check. I don't want to allow them to map to wrong columns no, but how do I prevent  a zip from going to an int column? especially if there are leading zeroes. I don't know how to validate that.

And your question is my question. I don't know. I'm not the db admin, and I'm not the user making whimsical choices about the csv structure, who knows where it's coming from. This was the task I've been given and I'm beginning to think it may be impossible, and we need some other kind of control in place

Comment: The crux of the issue is that if you allow users to import data willy-nilly without checking what is being mapped, your going to get messed up data, that's just how IT works.  Theres no way to tell (unless you have metadata and/or column headings) whether 23261 is a zip code in Richmond Va or the number of purchases processed by a chipotle location in a given month.

Comment: Which is the exact "crux" of my question. I'm TRYING to check it... I need a way to differentiate "#####" and "#####" but wait, they're the same format, how do I know which is which....? I have column headings, but I can't account for user input.

Answer (score 0):

In what ever programming language you use just do a regex, .length, + leading zeros.

```js
var string = 'asdf123';
var results = string.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
var count = 5 - results.length;
while (count > 0) {
  count--;
  results = '0' + results;
}
$('test').text(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<test>
</test>
```

Comment: this seems like a decent answer, but based on follow-up comments, OP seems very confused about what he needs, still helpful though

Comment: Not confused about what I need, but how to ask the question I guess. 

I have a 5 digit value. I need to programatically determine if it is an int, or string zip code, if it matches an existing zip code, how can I tell the user doesn't intend for it to be a string. 

The conversation has been helpful though in leading me back to requirement question for the client. So thanks guys!

Comment: If a user types a value in a zip code field, you should assume it is a zip code. You can validate it against the USPS and reject it, but beyond that, you can't question the intent of the user. Accept it or reject it. Those are your choices.

Comment: There are no fields, this is a csv table being generated from an uploaded file. If they map one column to a back end db column and the types don't match, there will be issues. 

This isn't a form, so I can't use masking because there is no user input aside from a drop down of backend db columns

Comment: figure out what needs to happen where "there will be issues" and you should be able to ask a clearer question